# Error 438 while generating a Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate an Pivot table in the sheet PW. 
I wanted to bring the values in the column Labels to Center, for this reason, I included the line

> .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

when I am including this i get an error

> object does not Support this property or method

here is the complete code, i am using for creating the Pivot table.

```
Sub status()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim pc1 As PivotCache
Dim pt1 As PivotTable
Dim ct1 As Integer
Set ws1 = Sheets("PW")
Set pc1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'BW'!R4C18:R1048576C29")
Set pt1 = pc1.CreatePivotTable(ws1.Range("A3"))
pt1.AddDataField pt1.PivotFields(" Mismatch"), "Sum of  Mismatch", xlCount
With pt1
With .PivotFields("Location in full form")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Mismatch"
End With
With .PivotFields(" Mismatch")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
End With
End Sub
```

could any one suggest, how i could bring the values in my Pivot column to Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply that property to either the `DataRange` or `LabelRange` properties of the pivot field (or both).

Comment: you mean to tell it should be DataRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Comment: Almost: `.DataRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter`